# Keras: Load multiple models and predict in different threads

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with tensorflow core. 
I want to load 2 different models in constructor,
and then make predictions (on request) in different threads. 
I tried to load these models within tensorflow graph contexts, but it didn't work. My code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import Sequential

def __init__(self):
    self.graph_A = tf.Graph()
    with self.graph_A.as_default():
        self.model_A: Sequential = load_model('model_A_filename')

    self.graph_B = tf.Graph()
    with self.graph_B.as_default():
        self.model_B: Sequential = load_model('model_B_filename')


def predict_with_model_A(X):
    with self.graph_A.as_default():
        return self.model_A.predict(X)


def predict_with_model_B(X):
    with self.graph_B.as_default():
        return self.model_B.predict(X)
```

When I run the program, model A is loaded successfully. However I receive an error on loading model B:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor     
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(7626, 210), dtype=float32) is not an element 
of this graph.
```

Will be happy to hear, how to do it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to reset the graph everytime after processing.
For keras use K.clear_session().
Use seperate sessions for every graph.

```
class Model:
   @staticmethod
   def loadmodel(path):
        return loadmodel(path)

def ___init__(self, path):
   self.model = self.loadmodel(path)
   self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()

def predict(self, X):
    with self.graph.as_default():
        return self.model.predict(X)

model1 = Model('model1.h5')
model1.predict(test_data)

model2 = Model('model2.h5')
model2.predict(test_data)
```