# How to use model.predict() function when loading two different models

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I trained two CNNs that are both binary classifiers. I build two classifier scripts that load the model and classify the images and that worked well. Beforehand I also have two preprocessing scripts where one just crops and normalizes the image and the other one crops, deletes a part of the image and normalizes the image.

Before I use my classifier script, I first let the preprocessor script run over the images. Now I want to merge all scripts together. So first my image should be preprocessed (Both models use the same images but concentrate on different parts). So I should have two images, one for model 1 and one for model 2. Then I use the `model.predict()` method for each model and load the corresponding image. But this time it does not work. One of my models always predicts the same class, but when I let it run seperately in one script it works fine.

for context: I have images of dies that could have a scratch or a broken edge. Since both errors could occur in parallel I trained two CNNs. One for detecting scratches and one for detecting broken edges. For the Scratch CNN I just crop the image so the image only shows the die. For the broken edge CNN I again crop the image and then black out the middle of the image so the CNN can just have a look on the edges. Now I want to use both models in the same script so I can sort out bad die images. If the scratch model sees a scratch the die has the status NOK. Likewise the status is set to NOK when the broken edge model sees a broken edge. It is also possible that there is a scratch and a broken edge, so both status are set to NOK. And if there is no scratch nor a broken edge both status are set to OK.

This leads to 4 cases, where either both status could be OK and NOK. The other 2 cases are when one of each class is NOK. The die should be classified as OK only if both are OK and as NOK if at least one class is NOK.

My current code looks like this:

```
import os
import time
from shutil import copyfile

import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.engine.saving import load_model

class ClassifierAgent:
    def __init__(self):
        #load scratch model
        self.scratch_model = load_model("C:\\Users\\but\\PycharmProjects\\OpticalDieInspection\\ScratchModel.h5")
        self.broken_edge_model = load_model("C:\\Users\\but\\PycharmProjects\\OpticalDieInspection\\brokenEdgeModel.h5")

        self.x = 125  # Fixed cropping dimensions for Carsten Problem
        self.y = 54
        self.height = 384
        self.width = 384
        self.dsize = (384, 384)


    def classify(self, input_dir, ok_dir, scratch_dir, broken_edge_dir):
        files = os.listdir(input_dir)
        image_files = [os.path.join(input_dir, f) for f in files if f.endswith(".jpg")]
        total = 0
        good_parts_cnt = 0
        bad_parts_cnt = 0
        for i in range(len(image_files)):
            start_time = time.time()
            total += 1
            img_input = cv2.imread(image_files[i])
            #crop out region of interest (die)
            crop_image = img_input[self.y:self.y + self.height, self.x:self.x + self.width].copy()  # Makes a copy of file
            #normalizing images before processing further
            temp = cv2.normalize(crop_image, None, 0, 255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
            #get height and width of cropped image
            h, w = crop_image.shape[0:2]

            #copy cropped image
            blacked_image = temp.copy()
            #black out text in the middle of the die
            blacked_image[27:h - 27, 27:w - 27] = 0

            scratch_input_image = np.expand_dims(temp, axis=0)
            #scratch_input_image = scratch_input_image.astype('float32') / 255

            broken_edge_input_image = np.expand_dims(blacked_image, axis=0)
            #broken_edge_input_image = broken_edge_input_image.astype('float32') / 255

            #cv2.imshow("scratch image", scratch_input_image)
            #cv2.imshow("broken edge image", broken_edge_input_image)
            #cv2.waitKey(0)


            output_scratch = self.scratch_model.predict(scratch_input_image)
            output_broken_edge = self.broken_edge_model.predict(broken_edge_input_image)

            if output_scratch[0][0] > output_scratch[0][1]:
                #print(output_scratch[0][0], "Scratch")
                part_state_scratch = "NOK"
            else:
                #print(output_scratch[0][1], 'OK')
                part_state_scratch = "OK"

            if output_broken_edge[0][0] > output_broken_edge[0][1]:
                #print(output_broken_edge[0][0], "BrokenEdge")
                part_state_broken_edge = "NOK"
            else:
                #print(output_broken_edge[0][1], 'OK')
                part_state_broken_edge = "OK"


            if part_state_scratch == "OK" and part_state_broken_edge == "OK":
                ok_dest = os.path.join(ok_dir, os.path.basename(image_files[i]))
                copyfile(image_files[i], ok_dest)
                good_parts_cnt += 1
            elif part_state_scratch == "NOK" and part_state_broken_edge == "OK":
                nok_dest = os.path.join(scratch_dir, os.path.basename(image_files[i]))
                copyfile(image_files[i], nok_dest)
                bad_parts_cnt += 1
            elif part_state_scratch == "OK" and part_state_broken_edge == "NOK":
                nok_dest = os.path.join(broken_edge_dir, os.path.basename(image_files[i]))
                copyfile(image_files[i], nok_dest)
                bad_parts_cnt += 1
            else:
                nok_dest = os.path.join(broken_edge_dir, os.path.basename(image_files[i]))
                copyfile(image_files[i], nok_dest)
                nok_dest = os.path.join(scratch_dir, os.path.basename(image_files[i]))
                copyfile(image_files[i], nok_dest)
                bad_parts_cnt += 1

            end_time = time.time()

            print("Image: ", files[i], "| Scratch: ", part_state_scratch, "; Broken_Edge:  ", part_state_broken_edge, " | ", total, "/", len(image_files))
            print('prediction time:', (end_time - start_time))
            # cv2.imshow("prediction", img_input)

            # cv2.waitKey(0)
            # cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_dir = "C:/Users/but/Desktop/Presence/Presence"
    scratch_dir = "C:/Users/but/Desktop/Evaluate/Scratch"
    broken_edge_dir = "C:/Users/but/Desktop/Evaluate/BrokenEdge"
    ok_dir = "C:/Users/but/Desktop/EvaluateBrokenEdge/OK"

    agent = ClassifierAgent()
    agent.classify(input_dir, ok_dir, scratch_dir, broken_edge_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a common thing that happens when you load several models on the same computer. The problem is memory management for the models. If you have only one GPU then Keras with its TensorFlow backend will allocate all GPU memory to one model. You can overcome this by deallocating and allocating your model memory. Basically, release the model from GPU and insert a new model into it. You can also try to work with that is called sessions.

Here are some useful links:

[How to release the occupied GPU memory when calling keras model by Apache mod_wsgi django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930871/how-to-release-the-occupied-gpu-memory-when-calling-keras-model-by-apache-mod-ws/52354865)

[Keras: Load multiple models and predict in different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248424/keras-load-multiple-models-and-predict-in-different-threads/53704563)

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8538

Comment: No, TensorFlow does not allocate all memory to one model

Comment: And what exactly do I have to do? I tried to use ```clear_session()``` between using ```predict()``` of the two models but I get a ```ValueError: Cannot create an execution function which is comprised of elements from multiple graphs.```

Comment: @NECben067 have you tried this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8538#issuecomment-358720718

For each model, you load them like that and make a prediction.